# Featured Image meta box not showing up

Tags: theme-development, multisite, post-thumbnails

I have featured images switched on in my theme:

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size(256,128, true);
add_image_size('icon', 128, 128, true);
```

but the Featured Image box isn't showing up anywhere when I edit a page. What's confusing is that the exact same theme, the same set of plugins and approximately the same data is working fine on another site. Is there some config setting that might prevent the Featured Image feature from working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked the "Featured Image" check-box within the "Screen Options" drop down menu beneath "Howdy, your username"? If that's not the case, we can look into it even further.

**Update:** WordPress MU users: Try going into "Network Admin", then click on settings, then enable image upload box, and save.

Comment: I checked, and the option for Featured Image isn't there on the Screen Options. It clearly doesn't think the theme has support - but I've established with judicious use of `die()` that the lines in my `functions.php` are being run.

Comment: Alright. Are using the latest version of WordPress? Try switching to the latest version of the twentyten theme for a brief moment to confirm that the Featured Image check-box is showing up or not.

Comment: I've established that both `post_type_supports('page', 'thumbnail')` and `current_theme_supports('post-thumbnails', 'page')` are true on the edit form page. That leaves multisite as the culprit - something to do with "media buttons"?

Comment: The media buttons - little icons above the content that add images etc - are indeed missing. So it doesn't believe there are any valid media types that could be used for a featured image.

Comment: If thats the case try going into "Network Admin", then click on settings, then enable image upload box.

Comment: I am on the latest version of Wordpress, 3.1.2. Switching to the TwentyTen theme does not solve the problem.

Comment: Enabling image upload in the network admin worked. I wonder why it was switched off? Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Marcus Glad it worked. Its disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone on **Wordpress 3.2.1 & Up** — The Featured Image option has moved into the Media Uploader. When you add an image, it shows up as an option under each individual image to set it as a the featured image.